# How to make higher order function that injects an argument into another?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that will inject something into another one.

In pure JS this would look like:

```
function add(a, b, c, d) { return a+b+c+d; }

function inject5(otherfunc) {
    return function(...args) { return otherfunc(5, ...args); }
}

const add5 = inject5(add);
```

How can I do the same in typescript?

```
function inject5<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(otherfunc: F) {
    return function(...args: ParametersWithoutFirstOne<F>): ReturnType<F> {
        return otherfunc(5, ...args);
    }
}
```

Of course I just made up this `ParametersWithoutFirstOne` thing.

More real use case I have in mind:

```js
const someService = injectUserRepository((userRepo: UserRepository, userId: string) => {
    userRepository.get(userId).doSomething();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples in rest parameters in the signature of the passed in function:

```
function inject5<A extends any[], R>(otherfunc: (n: number, ...a: A) => R) {
    return function(...args: A): R {
        return otherfunc(5, ...args);
    }
}

function add(a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number) { return a+b+c+d; }

const add5 = inject5(add);
add5(6, 7, 8);
```

This way the passed in function has to have a first argument of type number, and we get the rest of the parameters in `A`. We can then use `A` into a new function signature  as the rest parameter of the function.

This will apply exactly the same to your `UserRepository` example.

Comment: excellent, somehow I thought that using Parameters and ReturnType was the only way to do something fancy with functions-arguments. This turned out to be much, much easier than I expected :D